# How to get a value and its key from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, methods

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'0003': ['Mike', 'Restrepo', 'mtrepot', '87654321'], '0001': ['John', 'Jelenski', 'jelensohn', 'snf23jn4'], '0002': ['Clyde', 'Owen', 'clonew', 'dummy2015']}
```

And I need to search for a string inside a value list, let's say 'mtrepot' and return the key associated to it, '0003'. Is there a way to do it without lists nor tuples?

Comment: What do you mean is there a way to do it without lists? Do you mean is there a way to create the dictionary without lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*list comprehensions*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

```
>>> d = {'0003': ['Mike', 'Restrepo', 'mtrepot', '87654321'], '0001': ['John', 'Jelenski', 'jelensohn', 'snf23jn4'], '0002': ['Clyde', 'Owen', 'clonew', 'dummy2015']}
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if 'mtrepot' in v]
['0003']
```

Comment: `.items()` is a list of tuples, so does this meet the question's requirement to use neither lists nor tuples?

Comment: @ChrisMartin this is how OP should do it. and the question is *Is there a way to do it without lists nor tuples?*

Comment: In python3, `.items()` returns a "view" not a "list."

Comment: Either way, the answer uses a list comprehension, so we're doing this with a list.

Comment: @ChrisMartin sometimes the best way to help is by giving OP not what they want but what they need :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. One is provided by @user3100115. The other way could be to use generator function, for example:

```
d = {'0003': ['Mike', 'Restrepo', 'mtrepot', '87654321'], '0001': ['John', 'Jelenski', 'jelensohn', 'snf23jn4'], '0002': ['Clyde', 'Owen', 'clonew', 'dummy2015']}


def key_find(in_dict, value):
    for k in in_dict:
        if value in in_dict[k]:
            yield k


for key in key_find(d, 'mtrepot'):
    print(key)

#which prints: 0003
```